# How to get next SQL row when the PRIMARY KEY values are not continuous?

Tags: sql, sqlite

*INFO*:
* I have a table with an INT PRIMARY KEY column called "s_id".
* The values for "s_id" are discontinuous, i.e. [3,5,7,8,9,11,12,14).   So, [1,2,4,6,10,13] don't exist.

*QUESTION*:
**Given prior knowledge of "s_id" value '5', what is the simplest SELECT statement for pulling "s_id" value '7'?**

My latest attempt is hacky and arbitrary - the aim here being that if any rows exist I'd just pick the very first one and jump out:
 `SELECT s_id FROM s WHERE s_id > 5 AND s_id < (5+10)`

EDIT:  Sorry, I forgot to mention the limitation of SQLITE3, which does not offer 'TOP'.  Nick and Marc's suggestion of using "TOP 1" steered me in the direction of learning about that limitation 1st hand, and then toward "LIMIT 1", which ended up working great. I figured SQL was SQL, I should have known better though:
`SELECT s_id FROM s WHERE s_id > 5 LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT TOP 1 s_id
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE s_id > 5
ORDER BY s_id
```

That selects the first `s_id` value that's larger than 5 - in your case 7.

Comment: Don't you have enough rep?  Share the easy ones ;)

Comment: Thank you.  I forgot to mention that I'm using the "sqlite3" C library, so unfortunately TOP is not available.  Instead of 'top 1', I tried adding 'limit 1' at the end of the statement and it worked nicely.

Comment: @liutenantdan: yes, information like that would be extremely useful in your original post! Remember that for next time..

Answer (score 2):

`select top 1 s_id from s where s_id > 5 order by s_id`

Comment: +1 oky dokey :-) I like answering SQL question, however... :-)

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I assume this, and marc's, answer would work in regular SQL?     For those using sqlite3, which I forgot to mention in the original post, " limit 1" appears to be the ticket

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT s_id FROM s WHERE s_id > 5 ORDER BY s_id LIMIT 1;` in MySQL terms

Answer (score 1):

In English, you want the smallest s_id that's greater than 5. You can write it almost just that way in SQL.

```
select min(s_id) from yourtable where (s_id > 5);
```